# RecordCount Property not working

Tags: vba, excel, record-count

This is my code :

```
Dim conServer As ADODB.Connection
Dim rstResult As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Set conServer = New ADODB.Connection
conServer.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB; " _
& "DATA SOURCE=192.168.0.204; " _
& "INITIAL CATALOG=REPORTDB2; " _
& "User ID=sa;" _
& "Password="

conServer.Open

Set rstResult = New ADODB.Recordset
strSQL = "set nocount on; "
strSQL = strSQL & "select *  from Table1;"
rstResult.ActiveConnection = conServer

rstResult.Open strSQL

MsgBox rstResult.RecordCount, , rstResult.Fields(1).Value

With rstResult
    .MoveFirst
    Do Until rstResult.EOF
       Debug.Print abc & "," & .Fields(0) & "," & .Fields(1).Value
      .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
```

The MSGBOX Line showing me -1 as a RecordCount, but the same time rstResult.Fields(1).Value showing the first records value. Even I check through "do until...loop" all the records in msgbox or in debug window are perfectly showing.
The problem is it is not displaying or working recordcount property.

Comment: `RecordCount` only indicates number of records once the last record has been accessed. If you put `MsgBox rstResult.RecordCount` after your loop it will work. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821452.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `RecordCount` in that way.

It will give you the correct number of records only *after* you have looped through all records, but not *before* you have looped through the records.